# ubuntu 12.10.zram-config or zramswap-enabler?Which is better?

Tags: swap, ram

Which of this two are better for upstarting the zram?zram-config is available at software center.The other one is from ppa.

Answer (score 2):

zramswap-enabler is for Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10

Ubuntu 12.04 or newer should be using zram-config

[Zram](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html)